# Objective-C Auto-unboxing with LLVM 4

Tags: objective-c, autoboxing, llvm-clang

I've been looking at autoboxing in Objective-C ([here](http://club15cc.com/code/objective-c/objective-c-object-literals-quick-reference), for instance). Is there a new syntax for unboxing?

For instance, I want to do this but shorter:

```
NSArray *oneNumber = @[@1];
int one = ((NSNumber *)oneNumber[0]).intValue;
```

the second line's syntax is horrific. Is there any new language feature to deal with this?

Comment: Note that this is neither auto-boxing nor auto-unboxing.   The `@...` syntax for scalars and collections is, like the dot syntax, compiler shorthand for a concrete method call.  Autoboxing would imply that a bare scalar (`int x = 5;`) would be magically boxed when passed to a method that requires `NSNumber*`.  (KVC's `valueForKey:` is auto-boxing / un-boxing, for example).

Comment: Thanks for that, @bbum. Correct to call them "object literals?"

Answer (score 8):

```
[oneNumber[0] intValue]
```

Sometimes the old ways are best.

Comment: I always forget that there are limits to the dot syntax. +1 great point

Comment: Provided you KNOW in advance that oneNumber[0] responds to intValue call. Else you crash. I agree, however about the "old ways". Too much of a "good thing" may sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to stay in the object world. For instance:

```
NSNumber *one = @1;
NSArray *oneNumber = @[one];
one = oneNumber[0];
NSLog(@"one %@", one);
```